# How to install metronic theme (v5.1.1) on my local host?

Tags: angular, metronic

I purchased metronic theme recently.

I Downloaded the file and installed same as [documentation](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/documentation.html).

I installed node, yarn, gulp, git all successfully. ng serve command also compiled successfully, but nothing happen. I am unable to execute theme files.

installation_success

[image]

compiled screenshot

[image]

After ng server , browsed on the localhost:4200. But it's not executing properly, it displaying as below. Please check the image

[image]

How to install and execute the theme files? I am using latest version 5.1.1, i need angular default admin template.

Comment: it is better if you ask the same to the theme owner? They must have configured it some way and given steps.

Comment: might be the styles are not loaded properly. can you check console log in dev tools?

Comment: @Chakradhar did u get any response on this? Have you been able to successfully working  with this?

Comment: Yes, Latest version(5.1.5) installed successfully. I got the support from keen themes.

Answer (score 1):

I got the support from keen themes. Due to small syntax error in the code the version 5.1.1 not installed in my local host. They help me to how to fix.

I download the latest version 5.1.5 and installed successfully in local host without any issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to contact Keenthemes support, they will help you all the way or see the forum for extra support http://keenthemes.com/forums/

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Thanks you. I already contact the support 24 hours ago, They didn't respond yet. So i posted here, to get any quick response from already metronic theme users.